# What does "put the top down" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

Well, I have been searching the meaning of "put the top down", but I didn't find anything useful. Let me show you a little bit the context.

```
I'm gonna put the top down
I'm gonna talk about old times
I'm gonna put the top down
I'm gonna let myself unwind
I'm gonna put the top down
I'm gonna watch the day roll by
I'm gonna put the top down
This time.
```

It's the song's chorus. If you want to listen it, [click here](http://youtu.be/TJJS3rM1Rqk).

I was searching on [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=top%20down), they have two meanings of `top down` but I consider that they are not so appropriate.

If someone have any idea of what this phrase means, I will be happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I'm gonna put the top down" is a reference to a [convertible](http://rdd.me/7avfzvhp) sedan, which usually has a "cloth" top  that can be hidden behind the back seat. It allows the sun to shine on the passengers and the wind to blow through their hair. People do that when they want to feel "free" and relaxed.

It's just a metaphor for "unwinding" and "relaxing" and "talking freely", although it might also mean that the singer's actually driving a convertible while talking about old times.

Comment: This. +1. I do just that in mine.